# my chrome extension is published but not visible in web store

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-web-store

We had established our extension app on the chrome web store, and everything seems doing good.
But, there is still something wrong..I can not find the app by the search.

I can find my extension app by direct link.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ngfgdcjdnmbhpogjpjnchjfgnpjgooen/publish-delayed
But, when I search for it by the app name, the search result is empty.
It has been established several days, and the search in the chrome web store still can't find it.
Did I miss anything?

Comment: That link is a 404 for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have kept your extension visibility as Unlisted, change it to Public so anyone can search it on Chrome Web Store. To change visibility Go to Chrome Web Store Developer dashboard then Edit extension and Select Visibility as Public instead of Unlisted or Private.